# Почему фрэйм (tcp/ip стек) имеет такой вид?

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip

Привет.

На рисунке ниже показан фрэйм запроса (из wireshark) к DNS-серверу (мой комп спрашивает IP-адрес, который соответствует google.ru). Почему DNS-запрос имеет такой вид?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю так: когда данные проходит по уровням сетевой модели сверху вниз, то на каждом из уровней стека TCP/IP к данным добавляется информация - заголовок. Уровней всего 4, значит, и заголовков должно быть 4. А wireshark выдает 5 заголовков. На прикладном уровне добавляется заголовок DNS, на транспортном уровне - заголовок UDP (содержит порты отправителя и получателя), на интернет-уровне - заголовок IP (содержит айпи отправителя и получателя), на уровне линк - заголовок Ethernet (содержит MAC сетевой карты отправителя и получателя). **Что это за заголовок Frame 27???**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это информация от wireshark'a - поймал пакет, таким то размером, такого то числа на таком то интерфейсе, целый/побитый и тому подобное. Номера - это просто нумерация от начала сбора пакетов.

То есть, это метаинформация, которая добавляется самим wireshark'ом для удобства и дальнейшего анализа. Этой информации нет в пакете, либо она там есть "неявно" - к примеру, общий размер пакета.

Comment: спасибо. мне уже об этом сказали на другом форуме: The frame protocol isn't a real protocol itself, but used by Wireshark as a base for all the protocols on top of it. It shows information from capturing, such as the exact time a specific frame was captured. You could think of it as a pseudo dissector.